# range difference in Python 2.7 and Python 3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I ran the following code on Python 2 and Python 3

```
i = int(input())
for j in range(i):
    k = int(input())
    print(k*k)%(1000000000+7)
```

the input was was fed from a file containing the following

```
2
2
1
```

The Python 2 version ran fine but Python 3 gave this error

```
4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "solution.py", line 4, in <module>
    print(k*k)%(1000000000+7)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

why is this error occurring in Python 3 and how do i correct it

Comment: In Python 3, `print` is a function, so `k*k` is an argument to `print()` and then the result of printing (None) is given the `%` operator.  To fix, just put parentheses around the whole thing (excluding the actual `print` word, of course).

Comment: If you want to print the result of `(k*k)% (1000000000+7)` you have to wrap *the whole thing* in parenthesis: `print((k*k) % (1000000000+7))`. BTW: this produces the same result in both python and python3. (The output changes when you start using commas or keyword arguments...)

Answer (score 2):

In Python 2 it's parsing like this:

```
n = (k*k)%(1000000000+7)
print n
```

In Python 3 it's parsing differently, like this:

```
n = print(k*k)
n%(1000000000+7)  # TypeError
```

It's due to the changing of `print` from a statement into a function.  The return code of the print function is `None`, which you can't use with the remainder operator `%`.

Make yourself aware also of the differences between `input` on Python 2 and Python 3

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with `range`. You're just trying to use modulo on `None`, that's what the print function returns. Just reorder the parantheses like this:

```
print((k*k)%(1000000000+7))
```

Hope this helps!